# Google Cloud Error: The zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Apologies if this question comes off a bit ranty, but is this error supposed to be commonplace? I'm trying to use a compute instance with GPUs attached in the asia-east1 region. However I frequently (at this point every day) encounter this issue for hours at a time. Today I stopped the instance I was using for all of about 2 minutes before starting it again only to get this error. I've used AWS in the past and never had this issue. How are people supposed to use gcloud in any serious capacity when it seemingly never has enough resources available?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error message that appears from time to time. Many resources (CPUs, IPs, etc) in the Asia Regions/zones are at full capacity.

Also, note that if you are a [Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) user, you will not be able to use GPUs, if you want to use GPUs you might need [to upgrade your account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade)